# ngx-image-drawing image not being responsive

Tags: css, typescript, ionic-framework, responsive-images

When I use the plugin to load an image on a mobile device and the image is wider than taller it appears cropped as there is no space to show it completely.

Is there a way to load the image but responsively?

This is the library url:

https://github.com/GroupeCurious/ngx-image-drawing

I tried to search in the css where the image is being load but I wasnt able to find it.

Comment: Could you describe more what you want to happen when the viewport and image aspect ratios are not the same?

Comment: I want the image to take as much space as it can horizontally and to maintain ratio vertically, without cropping.